# Dynamic text lost its bold styling

Tags: flash

In the Flash IDE, I have made a dynamic text field bold. When the Flash is compiled and run, the bold styling disappears. How do I retain the bold styling?

**Top**: IDE

**Bottom**: SWF

[image: flash dynamic text]

Comment: Is that font embedded or only some characters embedded in that Textfield?

Comment: I think it is not embedded because I always get this compiler warning: "Fonts should be embedded for any text that may be edited at runtime, other than text with the "Use Device Fonts" setting. Use the Text > Font Embedding command to embed fonts."

Comment: Lol at that comment. Follow the instructions in the error and you'll be sweet.

Comment: I placed a checkmark next to uppercase, lowercase, numerals, and punctuation in the embed dialog box. It did not solve my problem. Also, why is it jumbling up my text? I set the text to "Error: The stream has stopped playing due to bad code." but it displays differently.

Comment: Also, I'm just using Arial. 99.9% of people should have Arial installed. Why do I need to embed it? It will increase the swf file size needlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing only the characters that were in the TextField initally, because they are automatically embedded, and you have the font lookup set to something other than "Use Device Fonts".

To fix the missing chars, change the font lookup to "Use Device Fonts", or embed both normal and bold "Arial".

The top TextField is not bold because Flash Pro sets the font style only on the text you entered at design time.  You can fix it by using `textField.htmlText = '<b>Bold Text</b>'` instead of `textField.text = 'Bold Text'`.

Comment: Unbelieveable... I thought that the trick was to embed the fonts - but whenever I did, my text completely disappeared as soon as the text attribute was changed. Using htmlText did the "bold" trick and the text does not disappear any more :) Thanks!